# get an MIME from an HTTP reply file

Tags: c++, python

i have successfully make a request and get a source page which begins with:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 30 Jul 2013 02:11:13 GMT
RallyRequestID: qs-app-061t71gj9w60m7graiwwkcihbo3.qs-app-061391284
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Content-Type: image/jpeg;charset=UTF-8
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=iteration_burndown.jpg
Set-Cookie: XSESSIONID=o44i037e364313anetibup7ux;Path=/analytics;HttpOnly
Vary: Accept-Encoding
P3P: CP="NON DSP COR CURa PSAa PSDa OUR NOR BUS PUR COM NAV STA"
Cache-Control: no-cache,no-store,max-age=0,must-revalidate
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

the rest part is the jpeg binary data

is there an exited lib in python or C++ that when given the length of whole file and the length of header, then it can get the jpeg out?

Comment: What is the context here? Is there some reason you're not using an existing HTTP client library, like [urllib2](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html) or [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/)?

Comment: actually I'm using libcurl, as you can see the response is encoded by chunked, I don't know to call which curl_easy_setopt settings can decode this file. Besides the response file I get is always hundreds KBs smaller than the real jpg, it is gziped~